# Oj::ParseError: not a valid ID number - "^rc"

Tags: json, ruby

Why the error raised when parsing json string(with Oj parser) that contains "^r" in combination with other character?

Error - "^r":

```
Oj.load("{\"s\":{\"s\":[\"^rc\"]}}")
=> Oj::ParseError: not a valid ID number at line 1, column 15
```

No error - "^b" or "^r":

```
Oj.load("{\"s\":{\"s\":[\"^bc\"]}}")
=> {"s"=>{"s"=>["^bc"]}}

Oj.load("{\"s\":{\"s\":[\"^r\"]}}")
=> {"s"=>{"s"=>["^r"]}}
```

How to know what are possible symbol combinations that can cause the error `Oj::ParseError: not a valid ID number`.
`Oj::ParseError` is to broad to be rescued - `An Exception that is raised as a result of a parse error while parsing a JSON document.`

Answer (score 2):

`Oj` is pretty much completely written in [c](/questions/tagged/c) so I am not going to reverse-engineer it to answer on the off-topic question “why is not code working.”

Some reverse-engineering of its *behaviour* is fine, though.

```
▶ Oj.dump(foo: "^bar")
#⇒ "{\":foo\":\"^bar\"}"
▶ Oj.dump(foo: "^rar")
#⇒ "{\":foo\":\"\\u005erar\"}"
```

That said, it *knows something* about `^r`. To overcome this issue, prepare your load:

```
▶ Oj.load("{\"s\":{\"s\":[\"^rc\"]}}".gsub(/\^/, "\\u005e"))
#⇒ {"s"=>{"s"=>["^rc"]}}
```

FWIW, latest `Oj` on my machine parses pretty fine your input as is without a glitch.

Comment: poorly formulated the question.
thanks, for sharing deep knowledge about "off-topic questions”. now it's only left to find out how many possible preparations need to be done. is gsub(/\^/, "\\u005e")) the only possible issue?

Comment: I have no idea.